# Inaccessible image in Perl blog post

Tags: bug, status-deferred, images, blog, accessibility

I noticed that the post [Why Perl is still relevant in 2022](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/07/06/why-perl-is-still-relevant-in-2022/) contains an SVG that is inaccessible to a number of users:

- When using a screenreader (VoiceOver), I hear "2009 image 2010 image 2011 image 2012 image 2013 image 2014 image 2015 image 2016 image 2017 image 2018 image 2019 image 2020 image 2021 image 2022 image image image image image image image image image image" and so on. However, this is clearly not what the image is of. The SVG should be aria-hidden and instead it should be labeled with screenreader-only text. I would describe it as a "graph showing the percent of questions in certain tags from 2009 to 2022. Perl decreased from 1% to nearly 0%, Bash stayed at around .5%, and Node.js increased from 0% to 3.25%" (maybe with more exact numbers).
- When using dark mode, the colors are not changed except for the background so the contrast is too low.
- When using a narrow screen (e.g. a phone), the right side of the graph is cut off, so you don't know what the lines mean.

[image: narrow graph light mode]

[image: graph dark mode]

I didn't look through any of the other blog posts, but if SVGs are handled the same anywhere else, they need to be changed. A quick fix (albeit sacrificing a little image quality) is to use a screenshot of the image from light mode with appropriate alt text.

Additionally, the link underneath the graph should be formatted instead of a bare URL.

Comment: It's genuinely infuriating that we have to keep reporting inaccessible images. They should really add image accessibility to a pre-post checklist for the blog editors, along with properly fact-checking _all_ posts (re: the recent Rust post that got factually destroyed over on MSE)

Comment: It also doesn't handle dark mode

Comment: @Nick wow, [that is in fact extremely difficult to read in dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYmsr.png).

Comment: I updated to status deferred. The Marketing team is looking into this. Although the chart is visible in dark mode it's not super legible. They are looking into if there is a a simple way for them to make an update on this post and will do so if there is.

Comment: Maybe worth checking on 'Stack Overflow Trends' where the Chart/SVG was [originally created](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=perl%2Cbash%2Cnode.js), (from the Link provided in the Blog), if you get the same (or better...?) Results with a Screen-Reader... :idea:

Comment: @chivracq It's the same SVG on that page. As a nitpick (in comparison), there are some other problems with the tool itself, like it says "Perl times bash times node.js times text input" instead of telling me that there are delete buttons for each tag and a text box to add another tag.

Comment: Ah!, the `xxx`, ah-ah...! I thought indeed it would be the same SVG. Nice to provide an "easy" Download Button, but the Tool/Sub-Site being from 'SO', it/they could also maybe generate/provide all the "necessary" HTML Metatags (`ALT` etc..., for Accessibility etc) (in a 'Code Block' for example) for "easy" re-posting/sharing in a Blog or any Site, I thought...

Answer (score 5):

[Asked and answered: the results for the 2022 Developer survey are here!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/22/asked-and-answered-the-results-for-the-2022-developer-survey-are-here/) has similar issues: it has three charts, all of which could easily be described in text.  All three are simply described as "Chart".

For example, this image:

[image: an image of a chart, described below]

should have been described as something like:

> A chart describing answers to the question "How often do you encounter knowledge silos at work?"  "Never": 32% of all respondents, 33% of independent contributors, and 27% of people managers.  "At least once a week": 68% of all respondents, 67% of independent contributors, and 73% of people managers.

Unfortunately, this lack of useful alt text seems to be par for the course for the blog.  To their credit, they got the alt text for *one* image correct: the first image is a pull-quote from the text above it, and thus its blank alt text is correct, as it's purely decorative.  However, blank alt text is frequently misused on the blog for images that simply did not have alt text written.

Comment: I checked with Marketing and they have added alt text to that post now.